# How to save the transaction scope with Task

Tags: c#, task, transactionscope

I want run tasks in TransactionScope ,
I work with like 400,000 records by 80 task of save (every save of 5000 records)
This is my code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.MaxValue))
            {
                try
                {
                    var tasks = new List<Task>();
                    foreach (var empsGroup in empsGroups)
                    {
                       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>  
                          {  
                           //add save of 5000 records      
                          }

                     }

                    Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
                    try
                    {
                        allTasks.Wait();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        scope.Dispose();
                    }

                    scope.Complete();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    scope.Dispose();

                }
            }
```

But I got exception:

```
message: System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

Comment: The using block will dispose the scope. There is no need to dispose it manually.

Comment: BTW Your exception handling is very bad.

Comment: sir-rufo -Thank, I will try.  (I removed for the forum my specific code of logs and throw)

Comment: Why dont you try `TransactionScope (System.Transactions.Transaction transactionToUse, TimeSpan scopeTimeout, System.Transactions.TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption asyncFlowOption);` variant of constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1) Increase the timeout. You may have to increase it pretty high, and a very long running transaction can interfere with other uses of the data.

2) Increase the performance (e.g. add indexes or CPUs) to meet the timeout. It might not be feasible if you're moving that much data.

3) Remove the requirement to use a transaction. Many times you can avoid a long running transaction by inserting into a temporary table, for example, as a staging area for a single SQL insert (which will run much faster than your thousands of tasks).

The third option would be my first choice in most cases.

Comment: Please note that OP has already used `TimeSpan.MaxValue` for timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8176478/mkr The time out happens after 11 minutes despite this setting